# Copying a Page in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, list, document-library

***Updated Question on 12/20/13)***

I am working in SP2013. My objective is to move a copy of a SharePoint document library and/or List Library to a site in another site collection. My thoughts were to create the List Library as a Template by doing the following: 
1. Go to the list or document library settings
2. Select Save As Template
3. Fill-out the fields > Save 
4. Go to the page where you want the copied page to be housed

...

Okay, I do not know what to do after that.  I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction, however I think these are the beginning steps. Has anyone successfully copied one page from a site to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To move a page (your original question):

If you go to the document library where the page is stored, you can download a copy of the page file without saving the whole site as a template.

So the correct operation would be:

- Navigate to the source file's document library (Pages, SitePages, etc.)
- Click the ellipsis next to the file
- Click the ellipsis in the popup
- Click "Download a Copy"
- Navigate to the destination document library
- Add the document via the upload

This will copy the page template without the contents.

<strike>The confusing thing here is that you say "(w/o content but keeps all column names... etc.)"... I don't quite understand what you mean by that.</strike>

## To copy a list or library as a template (your updated question):

To save the list as a template:

- In the ribbon go to list (or library) settings
- Click "Save list as template" or "Save library as template"
- Choose a file name and a template name. Do not click "Include Content" if you don't want the list contents.
- Save the list template (Click OK)

To use the template:

- When you save the template, there's a link to the List Template Gallery. You can click this link to navigate there, or paste `_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx` on the end of your site's URL.
- Click the checkbox next to your list template and then in the ribbon under the file tab click "Download a copy"
- If you don't want this list template available in the original site, you should delete it from the gallery after you've downloaded a copy of the .stp file.
- Navigate to the List Template Gallery of the destination site, and upload the .stp file there. The template should now be available to use.

Comment: Thank you, @RJ Cuthbertson for your response. I updated the question. The steps given seem as if this is moving one document to another document library, correct? Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome.  Worked perfectly.  Great input.  Thank you, RJ Cutherberton!